# Weird member reset in class

Tags: c++

I have a class in a static library like so:

connection.h

```
    struct impl;

    class connection
    {
    public:
        connection(boost::asio::io_service & io_service, std::string host, int port, std::string login_id, std::string authentication);
        ~connection();

        void initialize();

    private:
        //SFL::IO::SFIOManagerPtr* m_io_manager;
        //SFL::MSG::SFProtocolPtr* m_protocol;
        void timer_callback(const boost::system::error_code& error);
        impl* _impl;
    };
```

And the constructor:

```
connection::connection(boost::asio::io_service & io_service, std::string host, int port, std::string login_id, std::string authentication)
{
    _impl = new impl(io_service);
    _impl->_host = host;
    _impl->_port = port;

    //m_io_manager = new SFL::IO::SFIOManagerPtr(new SFL::IO::SFIOManager());
    _impl->_endpoint = new customendpoint(ST_API_SERVER, 0, login_id, authentication);

    std::cout << "connection" << std::endl;
}
```

Then I use this from an .exe :

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
snap::external_api::connection *conn = new snap::external_api::connection(io_service, "10.1.1.74", 5091, "mdl", "mdl");
//At this point, connection->_impl is initialized and valid.
conn->initialize();
//But here, when I go into connection::initialize(), the _impl member is null.
```

The problem is in comments in the last code sample. After the constructor, the members of `conn` are valid. But when the control goes inside `connection::initialize()`, the members (`_impl`) becomes `NULL`. Why is this happening?

EDIT :

```
class customendpoint : public SNClientEndpoint
    {
    public:
        customendpoint(int type, int tc, std::string loginId, std::string auth)
            :SNClientEndpoint(type, tc, loginId, auth)
        {
        }

        void OnOpen(const SFL::SFErrorCode& ec, bool& startRead)
        {
            Login();
        }
    };

    struct connection_settings
    {
        char type;
        std::string address;

        int id_type;
        std::string login_id;
        std::string authentication;
    };

    struct impl
    {
        int _client_type;
        customendpoint* _endpoint;
        bool _enabled;
        boost::asio::io_service& _io_service;
        connection_settings _conn_settings;
        boost::asio::deadline_timer _timer;
        std::string _host;
        int _port;

        impl(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
            :_io_service(io_service), _timer(io_service)
        {
        }
    };
```

And the `initialize()` function:

```
void connection::initialize()
{
    SFL::MSG::SFProtocolPtr protocol(new protocol_type()); /// protocol for DBAccess thread handler

    snap::ctrl::consumer::SNControl *control = new snap::ctrl::consumer::SNControl();
    control->Initialize(protocol);
    _impl->_endpoint->SetProtocol(protocol);
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of connection::initialize()? You should try once by commenting all code in connection::initialize().

Comment: @NTN : Yes, after commenting all code in `connection::initialize`, `_impl` is ok. But I don't do anything weird in the function.

Comment: `_impl` becomes NULL exactly when the control steps into `connection::initialize` function. Before even executing at least one line inside the function.

Comment: You're running a debug build, right?

Comment: @WhozCraig : Yes. It is debug. Both the static library and the .exe.

Comment: Does the toolchain you're using allow setting a memory-based break-on-write breakpoint? Its pretty trivial in VS and gdb.

Comment: Sounds like a compiler problem.  When inside the initialize() function, is the this-pointer set to the correct value?

Comment: Rebuild all? Yes, this sounds stupid, it always does, I know. But it might possibly save you hours of debugging time.

Comment: Yep, The `this` pointer changes when stepping into the function. Strange.

Comment: It's hard to find out exact cause until you share your definition of 'struct impl' & 'connection::initialize()'. Here, how you declared members of struct, and how you are accessing these member is need to be examined.

Comment: @NTN : Edited with the asked code.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi : Rebuilt everything. Still the problem persists. `this` pointer changes when stepping inside the function.

Comment: Ok, I created new projects for both the static lib and the .exe. Now it works fine it seems. Must have been some configuration error. I couldn't find any though. Thanks for the feedback anyway.